# Jasper report: detail band with several images with different heights

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to create a report for print several map legends. Right now I can generate the report with the title, and for each legend there is the name and the image below.

[image]

But all images are being resized to have the same height: the height of the container band (Detail 2 band).

[image]

I want that each image have its own height and not the height of the band.

How can I have images with different heights?

My report is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="legend" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="185" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="6b65086b-74e0-4bec-834b-1b74d5ae2d31">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="2.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="icon" class="java.awt.Image"/>
    <field name="level" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="25" splitType="Prevent">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$F{name}.equals("")]]></printWhenExpression>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="6" width="555" height="13" uuid="804c03e8-4edc-4888-8dba-0c683717bfeb"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{icon} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
            <image scaleImage="RetainShape">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="30" uuid="067c1436-8c32-4bd6-9fd2-db394dc7366a"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{icon}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/23446640

Comment: Try setting scaleImage="RealSize" for the image element.